# Diseño de formulario C# WPF con Looper

Tags: c#, wpf, controller

Estoy un poco perdido con el diseño de una idea usando formularios WPF.

Mi idea es crear un elemento contenedor y dentro de este tener varios controles que se repitan tantas veces como resultados me retorne una consulta a la BBDD. El problema lo tengo en la parte visual. No conozco un contenedor tipo Looper en WPF que me permita meter dentro de este por ejemplo unos Label y TextBox que tomen los valores que retorna la BBDD.

Este es un ejemplo (buscado aleatoriamente por Internet) de lo que necesito :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo necesito un poco de orientación, no necesito que nadie de vosotros pierda mucho tiempo en describirme el código fuente.

Muchisimas gracias y un saludo por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Seria posible acceder a los elementos del grid que se generan dinamicamente. Y modificar el contenido de un Label por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es lo básico de lo básico de WPF para usar eficientemente MVVM, databindings y olvidarte de la mitad de la codificación de la programación normal.

Lo que necesitas es el control "itemscontrol" 
dentro del DataTemplate tienes que definir los controles que contendrá y los databindings  necesarios al modelo o el datasource
(básicamente construyes un grid adentro y por cada elemento en tu colección de objetos creara un nuevo item

```
 <ItemsControl Name="ICLista">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo}" />
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progreso}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

En el back end hacemos que el source del ICLista sea una lista de objetos.

```
        List<Objetos> items = new List<Objetos>();
        items.Add(new TodoItem() { Titulo= "Complete this WPF tutorial", Progreso= 45 });
        items.Add(new TodoItem() { Titulo= "Learn C#", Progreso= 80 });
        items.Add(new TodoItem() { Titulo= "Wash the car", Progreso= 0 });

        ICLista.ItemsSource = items;
```

También podemos declarar el datasource en la definición del ItemsControl, pero para eso necesitamos que el Source fuera también de scope global(Razón por la que es mucho mas eficiente al implementar MVVM)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mike, me ha servido de gran ayuda la verdad que mas que perfecto. Solamente tengo una consulta mas, como puedo hacer para que si tengo 100 resultados (por poner un numero), se cargue una scrollbar para ver el resto de grid que no se muestran en pantalla. Gracias!

Comment: Vale ya me respondo yo mismo @Mike, es suficiente con envolver el código entre la siguiente etiqueta <ScrollViewer> </ScrollViewer>